# SQLite and Lua: Selecting column data from given row

Tags: sqlite, lua

How can i get value from one column in SQLite?
Example, i have column named `houseNames` and want to get value from third row, how can i do that?

Comment: What is `i` being used for in that call to `dbQuery`? Are you asking for help with the SQL query? Or with the lua code? Or both?

Comment: the `i` is the value of the row where i want to get value, it works perfectly.

Comment: What is `dbQuery`? Because that SQL query isn't using any arguments and appears to be calling an SQL function called `getFreeID` to determine which row to return... unless I've missed something fundamental here.

Comment: Okay i changed my main post

Comment: That just made the question much worse as it now contains no information about your situation at all and no indication that you've tried anything yourself (which is generally a prerequisite for getting help on this site).

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say whats your main purpose after your edit,
but its seems like you try to search sqlite3 wrapper for lua.
from my experience, [lsqlite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/home) will be good for your needs.

as for your question, the main use of this library is done by using iterators:

```
local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")

local db = sqlite3.open_memory()

for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM test") do
  print(row.id, row.content)
end
```

so you can get any details you want even by the column name which is more convenient than column number.

to get the n'th row from the db you can do :

```
local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")

local db = sqlite3.open_memory()
local stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM Players")
local maxRowNumber = 6
for rowNumber=1, maxRowNumber do
    stmt:step()
    row = stmt:get_named_values()
end
```

dont take this code as is, ive just wrote simple example, you should read the [api of lsqlite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki) first, and checks the sqlite3 return codes from each function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use SQLite to extract the given row directly. You obviously need some way of determining what 3rd row means, e.g. is it by rowid, some other field, houseName sorted alphabetically, etc.

Note: Rows in a database do not have any inherent order (in theory at least), not even the order the rows were added, and even if it may appear to be so there is no guarantee the rows SELECT-ed will be returned in any expected order unless an ORDER BY clause is given.

Once you have that you can use the LIMIT clause twice to get the needed row.  You need a query with a sub-query inside it.

In the sub-query you LIMIT the results to the row number you're looking for (say, 3).  In the outer query you sort in the opposite direction and LIMIT to 1.

Example:

```
-- assumes lsqlite3 already loaded as sqlite3

db = sqlite3.open(':memory:')

sql = [[
create table t(houseNames text);

insert into t values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f');
]]

db:exec(sql)

sql = [[
select houseNames from (select houseNames from t order by houseNames limit 3)
  order by houseNames desc
  limit 1;
]]

for house_name in db:urows(sql) do
  print(house_name)
end

db:close()
```

You can also use a LIMIT with OFFSET clause and avoid the sub-query:

```
sql = [[
select houseNames from t order by houseNames limit 1 offset 2
]]
```